# Why does C++ containers not have a contains method?

Tags: c++, syntactic-sugar

Checking membership is one of the most frequently used operations in any programming languages, but C++ insists that programmers use the verbose `container.find(value) != container.end()` instead of the readable `container.contains(value)`. What is the rationale behind not adding a syntactic sugar for this operation?

Comment: Both `*set`s and `*map`s will have `contains` from C++20.

Comment: And worse, not all containers even have a specialized `find()` method, so you have to use `std::find()` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau But you _shouldn't_ for containers that _do_! Argh!

Comment: "*Checking membership is one of the most frequently used operations in any programming languages*" Citation needed. Getting the element you found is often of greater value than merely testing membership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true for all containers. For example; `std::set` has a `.count()` member function, that is essentially the same as `contains`, in that it will return `0` if the container does not contain an element and `>0` if it does. There's also `std::any_of` which works for all containers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to check if a container contains an object: [`std::any_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of). This is also more flexible since it takes a predicate to determine if the object is in the container.

Comment: Being as this works on iterators, it's unsuitable for use cases like sets and maps.